# using windbg for monitoring a memory leak

Tags: windows, debugging, windbg

Monitoring a memory leak using WinDbg ? I am looking for a way to get a deeper stack-trace using !htrace (!htrace enable --> !htrace -snapshot --> !htrace -diff) to nail down a MEM leak we are having. I can currently get the stacks of threads holding onto resources, but I can't get deep enough stacktraces (I would like to see more frames on each stack.. I only see the parts in stack which are less interesting to me)

Comment: Are you finding that you are seeing only 20 frames? this is the default you can change this using `.kframes 0n100` will set it to 100 frames, ther other issue have you set the user stack trace on in gflags? To do this `!gflag +"ust"`

Answer (score 0):

By default 20 is the stack frame limit, you can change this:

```
.kframes 0n100
```

This sets the limit to 100 (the `0n` indicates the number is decimal based, otherwise it will assume you are passing an hexidecimal value) more info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/hardware/ff563850%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).